# Find The Correct Page Of An Item Index

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I couldn't quite find the right title for my question, sorry for that.

In what I'm working on the user is given a paged menu with a list of options, however this paged menu can only display 7 options/items per page, and the user must scroll between pages to see all of the items.
Later on, the user may be sent back to the exact page of the chosen option, my dilemma is to find the best algorithm to get find the correct page number of the item index.

So say option index is 4 then page is #1, or index is 23 than page is #3, and so on...

I have written this algorithm:

```
def _getIndexPage(index):
    items = 7
    page = 1
    while items <= index:
        items += 7
        page += 1
    return page
```

So while the index number is greater than or equal to the number of items I keep adding 7 to 'items' and 1 to 'page', and when its not, returns the final result of 'page'.

This does the job well, but I never really felt that is the right way to do this, so I'm looking for a maybe a simplified way to do this, is there a better option?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shorter and more efficient way of writing your algorithm and making the number of items per page flexible:

```
import math
def _getIndexPage(index, items_per_page=7):
    return int(math.ceil(index / items_per_page))
```

Comment: Beautiful! That so did the job even better!
Much appreciated!

Comment: Well done! I had hard time interpreting qeustion, was just offering ideas, you got it gj!